Editing questions/answers
I am sure that every once in a while, editing posts (Q's and A's) are great. The thing I am confused about is that when I edit someone else's post, sometimes there is just 1 thing I have to fix and sometimes there are multiple things. When I click the "Edit" button at the bottom, it just edits the post (and goes throught the queue) even though there is 1 thing I edited (grammar or spelling on one word). However on other sites (let me know if this should go to the main Meta and not here), it tells me that I did not edit enough things? Is there a privilege that causes editing posts to be shorter? Did I not read carefully if there is one?

Jadon Jung - Hi, Unfortunately I don't understand most of the question :( (Perhaps others do.) Are you comparing behaviour on this site vs. other SE sites? Or are you comparing small edits vs. longer edits, both on this site? Are you referring to an error message when making short edits, something like "Edits must be at least 6 characters"? (Mods don't have that restriction, so I can't get the exact message text.) || You mention editing "1 thing" but what is the "thing". Do you mean 1 character or something else? TY

Jadon Jung - I see you have edited the question. However it didn't answer some of my earlier clarification questions, so I don't have enough clarity to continue and I'll stop here. Hopefully other people can understand better than me and can help you. BR

You are allowed to edit any of the posts you wrote (Questions or Answers) without restrictions.  For example, assume you accidentally typed the word "too" instead of "two".  You can fix your typo by editing your post.
However, there are restrictions for editing posts written by other users.  For example, since your reputation on the EE.SE site is currently 307, you do not have the privilege to make such a small edit.  Refer to the Help Center for a discussion about editing.  The privilege to make small edits is awarded at 2,000 reputation.

toolic - Hi, Thanks for trying to help the OP. I didn't interpret the question the same way you did - perhaps that's my failing :( The OP doesn't have 2000 rep on any SE site currently, yet they seem (I think?) to be claiming a difference in behaviour between different SE sites (?). I don't understand :( If they had 2000 rep on some sites, not others, then that could explain a difference in observed behaviour - but they don't. || Perhaps any reply to your answer will also help clarify the question :)

@SamGibson: I agree that the question could use some clarification.  There should be no difference for this user between SE sites.  The only diff I can think of is that the user might have edited their own post vs. trying to edit someone else's.

toolic - Yes, editing their own post (no minimum edit length & immediate visibility of the change) vs. editing other people's posts (minimum edit length of 6 characters, I think, and needing to go through the review queue as a suggested edit) will be different. Hopefully the OP can clarify. Thanks again.


it tells me that I did not edit enough things?

There could be some site differences with regards to this, I am not aware of any ways to set editing limits.
Just some pointers for people that edit:

Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post
significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you
observe

Also, try not to edit closed questions and questions that are unslavagable. Try to stick to editing questions that are useful.
Also this from the main meta FAQ:
Editing and Formatting

How does editing work? 
How do suggested edits work? 
Why is the edit button disabled? 
What is a 'rollback'? 
Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer? 
How do I format my code blocks? 
List of Sandboxes 
Denoting keyboard shortcuts in Stack Exchange posts 
What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites? 
How to nest code within a list using Markdown 
How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post? 
How to upload an image to a post? 
What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link? 
What should I keep out of my posts and titles? 
Why does the Community user sometimes review suggested edits? 
What is syntax highlighting and how does it work? 

